# Slider with years for barplot

Tags: r, shiny, slider, bar-chart

I am trying to get a slider within my barplot page to make the data interactive per year.

```
#library

library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(ggplot2)

#Source
dataset <- read.csv("Wagegap.csv")

SFWage <- dataset %>% 
  group_by(gender,JobTitle, Year) %>%
  summarise(averageBasePay = mean(BasePay, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
              select(gender, JobTitle, averageBasePay, Year)

clean <- SFWage %>% filter(gender != "")


#UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  theme = shinytheme("united"),
  
  navbarPage("San Fransisco Wages",

             tabPanel("Barplot",
                    
                      mainPanel(
                        plotOutput("barplot")
                        
                      )) ,
             tabPanel("Table", 
                      mainPanel(
                        dataTableOutput("table")
                      ))                     
  )
)                       
       
#server
server <- function(input, output){
  
  output$barplot <- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(clean, aes(x = JobTitle, y = averageBasePay  ))+
    geom_bar(stat="Identity", width = 0.3, fill="orange")+
    labs(x= "Jobs", y = "Wage", title = "Wage per job")
   
})
  
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    clean
    
  })
}
  
  #Run App
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I don't fully understand it yet how to put this input in.
I have tried sliding it into the navbarpage but I can't figure out how it works.
I also tried making year reactive but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the year that has to be reactive; it's the whole data frame. Therefore, in your ui, you can do:

```
[...]
tabPanel("Barplot",
                      
                      mainPanel(
                        sliderInput("year", label = "Which year should be displayed?", min = 1900, max = 2020, step = 5, value = 2000) # new
                        plotOutput("barplot")
                        
                      )) ,
[...]
```

I put it there for convenience; the layout is yours. I tried do change as little as possible.

The server would then have:

```
server <- function(input, output){
  
  # NEW ########################################
  clean <- reactive({
    SFWage <- dataset %>% 
      group_by(gender,JobTitle, Year) %>%
      summarise(averageBasePay = mean(as.numeric(BasePay), na.rm=TRUE)) %>% # Notice the as.numeric()
      select(gender, JobTitle, averageBasePay, Year)
    
    SFWage %>% filter(gender != "" & Year == input$year)
  })
  
  # OLD ########################################
  output$barplot <- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(clean(), aes(x = JobTitle, y = averageBasePay  ))+ # Parenthesis
      geom_bar(stat="Identity", width = 0.3, fill="orange")+
      labs(x= "Jobs", y = "Wage", title = "Wage per job")
    
  })
  
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    clean() # Parenthesis
    
  })
}
```

Don't forget to add the parenthesis, as I did here.

This should work, but I might have mistyped something or got it completely wrong. Since I don't have your data, I can't test it.

EDIT: Due to your comment, I added the `as.numeric()` term, as you can see above. However, if your data is not only not numeric but also with `,`, you can do:

```
[...]
      summarise(averageBasePay = mean(as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", BasePay)), na.rm=TRUE)) %>% # Notice the as.numeric() and the gsub()
[...]
```

Comment: The slider works but I can't test if it reacts with the data, because It wont calculate the mean of basepay. The data is character. Where should I paste the as.numeric(gsub(".", ",", BasePay)) code in?

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to put "," instead of "." in your data. `as.numeric()` works on `"10.12"` (for example), and not `"10,12"`.

Comment: In a different post someone posted   ''probably because they have "." decimal seps while your locale uses ",". Try `as.numeric(gsub(".", ",", BasePay))''

Comment: NAs introduced by coercion is what I get if I place as.numeric(dataset$basepay) above the SFWage <- code

Comment: Ok, so do my `gsub()` in reverse: instead of `as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", BasePay))`, you do `as.numeric(gsub(".", ",", BasePay))`

Comment: Error in function_list[[i]](value) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double' if i place the code within the pipeline of SFWage <-